# How to solve material design input field placeholder screen reader issue with Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, accessibility, placeholder, screen-readers

I am using material design with floating label for the input field.
There is some scenario to use placeholder text for announcing extra details to the user. For the inactive/blurred text field I can not add the placeholder (label and placeholder text will overlap each other) so I toggle placeholder text on input field focus in/out.

It's working fine in JAWS along with Chrome, announcing: `<label> <placeholdertext>`

But with Firefox it is announcing only `<label>` and placeholder is missed out as it's being added dynamically.

Is there any fix available for this situation?

I am assuming if there is no fix, I may need to add the placeholder text along with label and there could be spacing issues in the future.

[image: Label text - Input tex…]

Comment: I recall having trouble with placeholder text a couple of years ago - some browsers hide it on the focus event, but some wait for a keypress event. Could it be this that's stopping Firefox announcing it?

Comment: thanks @Tokn for writing, tried with pressing some characters but still, it is not announcing placeholder text. additional note, am adding placeholder attribute on focus event of the text field.

Comment: So does JAWS on Firefox announce the placeholder text properly if you've hardcoded it in? If it does, then it's the fact that you're adding the attribute on focus that's the problem, and I guess the screenreader event for the field is triggered before your placeholder has been populated.

Comment: oh thanks for hinting, Observed placeholder is not getting read when there is proper label association with for attr.  so it is not because placeholder attr toggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved by toggling `title` along with `placeholder` attr. now screen reader on both browsers(FF & chrome) announces `<label> + <title>` and `placeholder` attr is ignored. this solved accessibility issue with placeholder issue on FF  browser.

(or)

aria-describedby attribute is added on input field and assigned value as id-value of same input field. so this way screen reader announces `<aria-describedby> + placeholder`, and aria-describedby is pointing to label value indirectly as input tag's id-attr is pointing to label's for-attr. this works similar in chrome and FF